# Osm to Shapefile -- missing polygons

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

**Problem:**

I am using ogr2ogr to convert osm file to shp and some features realated to the lakes are missing. I noticed for ex. lake is missing when it is flow-through lake (river is at both ends).

**My result**

Shapefile with some lakes but many are missing.

**Question**

Can someone tell me what I can do to get those missing lakes?

**Part of my Osmconfig.ini**

closed_ways_are_polygons=natural=water

[multipolygons]

attributes=natural

**Picture:**

You can only see river polygon here but there was no point to add any more layers, because I am interested in river and lakes.

rose polygon = river polygon

basemap = OSM Basemap in ArcGIS Pro

[image]

**Edit:**

I found out that when lake is within 'relation' it is correctly converted to the record in the shp, but when lake is within 'way' it is missing in shp.

**Version:**

GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14

Comment: Have you tried keywords for `waterway` such as `riverbank` ?

Comment: can you share more info about the extract area (bounding box)? That's a great suggestion from @J.Monticolo and I suspect that's what is happening here.

Comment: For my answer, I've found the area on OSM and looked into the feature : https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=wloclawek#map=13/52.6334/19.2822

Comment: Have you tried to add a type (polygon)?

Comment: Maybe try to define waterway=riverbank and waterway=river after your attributes=natural as a new line for each waterway declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a copy of your Osmconfig.ini, I've put here my solution for achieving the extraction of this Poland's water stream :

1. Download the [PBF file](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/poland/kujawsko-pomorskie-latest.osm.pbf) from Geofabrik (one of OSM Download Center)
2. Run a terminal and use the following code :

   `ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" kujawsko_pomorskie_water -sql "select * from multipolygons where hstore_get_value(other_tags, 'waterway') = 'riverbank'" -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 kujawsko-pomorskie-latest.osm.pbf`
3. Go to the new `kujawsko_pomorskie_water` directory and open `multipolygons.shp` with your favorite GIS app (mine is QGIS !)

Comment: I can't run it via terminal.
C:\Users\xxxxxx>cd E:\Testowanie_osm\kujawskie
C:\Users\xxxxxx>ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" kujawsko_pomorskie_water -sql "select * from multipolygons where hstore_get_value(other_tags, 'waterway') = 'riverbank'" -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 kujawsko-pomorskie-latest.osm.pbf
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `kujawsko-pomorskie-latest.osm.pbf' with the following drivers.

Comment: Can you add in your original post your GDAL version, command `ogr2ogr --version` please ?

Comment: Thanks for the version. The second command line is exected in C:\. Try this : `ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -f "ESRI Shapefile" kujawsko_pomorskie_water -sql "select * from multipolygons where hstore_get_value(other_tags, 'waterway') = 'riverbank'" -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 E:\Testowanie_osm\kujawskie\kujawsko-pomorskie-latest.osm.pbf`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also a time ago when converting .pbf to spatialite.  (https://github.com/osmbe/qgis_rendering/blob/master/qgis-loves-spatialite.md)

As @J. Monticolo suggested, the problem was due to the tag waterway=riverbank. I changed that tag in OpenStreetMap to natural=water + water=river (or canal, or ...), and then it was added to the layer.

I didn't want to change every tag, so I found a sollution.  I did it with QGIS DB-manager, but I think it would go with every spatialite-reading gis-software.

Activate the spatialite-DB and run following query.

```
insert into multipolygons (GEOMETRY, osm_id, other_tags)
select CastToMultiPolygon(BuildArea(GEOMETRY)) as geometry, osm_id, '"waterway"=>"riverbank"'
from lines
where waterway =  'riverbank'
```

This will search in the layer 'lines' after the way tagged as 'riverbank' and convert them to a polygon.